# Association without foreign keys and make join in table

Tags: mysql, model, sequelize.js, associations

I am working on Node + sequelize  + mysql. All the things is working fine in my code. Now i need to add search field in list page. In this search page there is showing user first name, last name, company name and status. I got all data from one table but company comes from "Company" table. In user table there is company_id. I can not make association for company_id. Now i want to search from company_name too. How i add include without association.

```
const { User, Company } = require("../models"); 

if(query.trim() != "") { 
        [err, users] = await to(User.findAll({
            where : {[Op.or] : {first_name:{ [Op.like]: '%'+query.trim()+'%' },last_name:{ [Op.like]: '%'+query.trim()+'%' }}}, 
            include : [
                {
                    model:Company,
                    where : {company_name:{ [Op.like]: '%'+query.trim()+'%' }}
                }],
            limit: 5,
            offset: 0,
            order: [[id, ASC]]
        }));
        console.log('err ----------------',err);
        console.log(users);
}
```

I got below error on from above code :

```
err ---------------- { filename:
   '/var/www/html/fullproject-name/backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js',
  line: 583,
  row: 13,
  message: 'Company is not associated to User!',
  type: 'SequelizeEagerLoadingError',
  stack:
   'SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Company is not associated to User!\n    at Function._getIncludedAssociation..... }
```

User Model Code  :

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    var Model = sequelize.define('User', { 
        email: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true, unique: true, validate: { isEmail: {msg: "Phone number invalid."} }}, 
        company_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
        last_name: DataTypes.STRING, 
        active:DataTypes.INTEGER, 
    });

}
```

Company Model Code :

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var Model = sequelize.define('Company', {
    company_name: DataTypes.STRING, 
    company_attachment: DataTypes.STRING,
  });
   }
```

Comment: Googlers may be interestd in `constraints: false` to create an association without `FOREIGN KEY`: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7104 | https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-hasMany

Answer (score 0):

You need to [associate your models](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/docs/associations/) with each other in order to be able to query them together with joins. In the below sample, I added some associations for `User` and `Company`. The relation I defined (which you can change) is one to many. A user belongs to one company; a company has many users.

This association will put a foreign key of `company_id` on the `User` model.

```
const models = require("./models.js") // Update if necessary
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var User = sequelize.define("User", { // Changed from Model to User
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
      unique: true,
      validate: { isEmail: { msg: "Phone number invalid." } }
    },
    company_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    last_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    active: DataTypes.INTEGER
  });

  User.belongsTo(models.Company); // User to Company association
};

const models = require("./models.js") // Update if necessary
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var Company = sequelize.define("Company", { // Changed from Model to Company
    company_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    company_attachment: DataTypes.STRING
  });

  Company.hasMany(models.User); // Company to User association
};
```